# Make a flex item grow at hover without affecting the other flex elements

Tags: html, css

I have box elements in a flex container. I want the paragraph in a box to display when hovering over the box. However, the hovered box makes the other boxes grow too. Is there a way to avoid affecting the other boxes when hovering one box? 
I would try: *align-items:flex-start*, but I want the boxes to be equivalent in height when they are not hovered. 
So *align-items:flex-start* does not keep the boxes' height equivalent when they are not hovered. 
I want the box to enlarge when hovered without affecting the other boxes and turn back to the equivalent height when not hovered.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/lemour-sudo/pen/yLMQOpE

```css
.container > * {
  width: 25em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 3em 10em;
  border: solid 3px green;
}

p {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  border: solid 3px red;
}
.box:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam tenetur amet dignissimos, accusantium molestias tempora!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto voluptatum labore totam natus illo, magni inventore cupiditate hic omnis ipsam vero nobis enim dicta perferendis facilis tenetur quaerat! Voluptas, voluptatum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: align-items:flex-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `align-items` property so that flex children doesn't stretch:

```css
.container>* {
  width: 25em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: start;
  margin: 3em 10em;
  border: solid 3px green;
}

p {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  border: solid 3px red;
}

.box:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam tenetur amet dignissimos, accusantium molestias tempora!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto voluptatum labore totam natus illo, magni inventore cupiditate hic omnis ipsam vero nobis enim dicta perferendis facilis tenetur quaerat! Voluptas, voluptatum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Can it enlarge without expanding the container parent itself?

Comment: @Becay I guess you'll have to set a height to the container (so that it stays with that hight and children overflows it), if height is `auto` it'll grow. Otherwise you'll have to use things like `float`, `absolute` positioning the extra popup content etc so that it doesn't count towards the height of content in normal flow